# Turn-by-turn GPS navigation app on iOS using Google Maps?

Tags: ios, google-maps, navigation, gps

I know this questions is asked several times and it seems Google terms & conditions agreement doesn't allow for apps using navigation. Also I know there are few third party libraries which can do the same task.

But my client need to do it using Google Map SDK and saying it can be done using paid APIs. I couldn't find any reliable resources to convince him that he is correct or wrong. Thus, I wonder how apps like Uber do this trick in their apps? What are the other options do I have?. Thanks.

Comment: There are some third party apis & services like D'Carta, pigtone etc who provides turn by turn navigation. But why are you doing this. Implement Apple's native Map request APIs to get al this feature done.]

Comment: Its my client need actually. He don't like to use any other 3rd party libraries except google map sdk. Cannot convince him to use Apple maps since google map is so accurate and mature in most cases.

Comment: your client told: "and saying it can be done using paid APIs." Really which ones?

Comment: Just to follow up on the original question, the second part. I have the same question really. How exactly do other navigation apps do it? Uber, Hailo , im sure there are plenty of other lesser known navigation apps.


E.g. Rungo , you can save a route on your phone (and it definitely uses Google maps api) and then do that route with turn-by-turn voice navigation.

Any ideas? Its just Im in a similar situation to the client where I am about to tell them its not possible, but I dont really know why if others are doing it.

But at the same time I can see Googls T&Cs alright

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this cannot legally be done.

Even Google does not have the right to allow the usage for Turn-by_Turn navigation. Google gets their digital road maps mainly from TomTom, and they just do not allow that, because they want to sell their own navigation devices.
It might be possible to sign a contract with TomTom and Google for special data delivery. But you can expect extreme costs, per year per navigation device.

The other professional digital road map provider is Here maps(former Nokia).
I don't know if and under which condition they provide a routing service.

Be warned, developping a navigation system is a very complex task, I know a company that invested 1000 person years, after some years on the market,  that company stopped their activities.

Check first whether it is legal to use Apples API, and then use that, or forget the app.

Comment: @AlexWien I wrote a comment in the main question, Im wondering what are your thoughts on that. Its the same question really , but I guess Im just baffled as to how other nav apps can do it!. Thanks for any help